# How to copy branch without specified commits in GIT?

Tags: git

For example, I have master branch which looks like :

```
master -x-x-x-a-x-a-a-x-x-x-x-a-x-x-a-x-x-x-x-a-a-a-x-x
```

How can I 'copy' master branch only with commits called **X** without **A** commits. I know I can use `cherry-pick` but it is too anoying...

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what distinguishes an X commit from an A commit?

Comment: tried `git branch` + `git rebase -i master` and remove the commits that you don't like?

Comment: `git rebase -i master` adds one additional commit but I don't want to get a new commit...

Comment: What do you mean that it adds an additional commit? What's in this additional commit?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some automatable criteria by which you can distinguish A commits from X commits, the easiest way to do this is indeed via an interactive git rebase. Let's say the first commit you want to copy from `master` is `abc123`; do:

```
git checkout master -b new_branch
git rebase -i abc123^
```

Your editor will open up with a list of all the commits. Remove the ones you want to skip, and close the editor. After that, `master` will be unchanged, and `new_branch` will point to your copies.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by “`'copy'`” (including why you put it in your own quote marks), but in fact, if you want to take a series of existing commits, turn them into change-sets, then make a branch that starts from some base commit and takes some of the change-sets (but not all) and makes a new branch out of those, it *must* be a copy (by definition) and you most likely will need to use cherry-pick to do it.

> I know I can use `cherry-pick` but it is too anoying...

You don't say how or why it is "too annoying" but in general the trick is to automate the cherry-picks you want.  This is what `git rebase` does: used non-interactively, it simply cherry-picks everything, and used interactively, it opens your chosen editor on a sequence of cherry-pick commands.

You also have not answered the question about distinguishing desired and undesired commits.  This will be the key to automating your cherry-picks.  For instance, if every commit you want to keep has the word `green` in its one-line subject, and/or every commit you want to omit has the word `red`, you can get a list of commit IDs, run through the IDs to select the keep/discard commits, then run an automated `git cherry-pick` on the kept IDs:

```
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order HEAD~20..HEAD > /tmp/all-ids

for id in $(cat /tmp/all-ids); do
    if git log -1 --pretty=%s | grep green; then echo $id; fi
done > /tmp/keep-ids

git checkout -b newbranch HEAD~20
git cherry-pick $(cat /tmp/keep-ids)
```

for instance (this assumes `HEAD~20` is the first commit before the chain to keep-or-discard; if the chain goes all the way to a root commit you'll need to modify the strategy a little bit, so that the new branch starts out as a new, empty, orphan branch).

The first line simply lists all candidate commits, sorted in commit order rather than any date order (note that this also assumes there are no merges).

The loop `for id in ...` runs through all the candidates and selects the ones to keep.

The `checkout -b` and `cherry-pick` commands make the new branch starting wherever you want to start, and pull in the "to keep" commits.  Note that `git cherry-pick` may stop and need help from you if some of the to-be-kept commits cannot be applied as-is because of something that was omitted.